# Remove Json-ld for base-path from Joomla 3.x header

Tags: joomla3.0

Since the last versions of Joomla the `<jdoc:include type="head" />`add

```
<script type="application/json" class="joomla-script-options new">{"system.paths":{"root":"","base":""}}</script>
```

to the Header.

How can I remove the Json-ld without modify the core? Is there a comand for this?